# Is there a molecular addon for 2.8?

Tags: add-on

I've installed the molecular addon in 2.8 release but the options are no where to be found, wondering if there's a 2.8 supported version somewhere or if i need to get 2.79 to use it

Answer (score 4):

Haven’t tried it ,but scorpion81 updated it for 2.8. https://github.com/scorpion81/Blender-Molecular-Script/releases

Answer (score 0):

## No.

As you can see on http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-download/ the last version is for 2.77.